# update textinput value by selecting a dropdown list in yii 2

Tags: php, forms, yii

I'm very new to Yii and I'm trying to update a value of an textinput , depending on the value selected on a dropdown list. in my view I have this inside my active form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'quantity')->textInput(['readonly' => !$model->isNewRecord]) ?>//this is an integer

<?= $form->field($model, 'allowquantity')->dropdownlist(['yes' =>'yes','no'=>'no']) ?>
```

I want to be able to change the value of the field quantity, depending on the selected value in dropdownlist. example, if i choose yes in the dropdown, it will retain the value in the quantity field. I choose no , it will turn the value to 0. this will happen in my update form so that i can update the values in the database. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your dropdown , make sure `#quantity` is the id of quantity textbox

```
echo $form->field($model, 'allowquantity')->dropDownList(['yes' =>'yes','no'=>'no'], 
             ['prompt'=>'-Choose a option-',
              'onchange'=>'if($(this).val() == "no"){
                 $("#quantity").val("0"); }'
              ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , will try and feedback soon. :)

Comment: ramamoorthy_villi, I tried your code but it doesn't change. when I select no from the dropdown, the value of quantity remains the same.

Comment: what is id of quantity textbox ?